# How to redirect URLs with percent encoded characters and query strings?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, 404

I have these URLs:

1. `http://www.example.com/example.html%20text-decoration:%20none%E2%80%9D%3Eexample.com%3C%20%3C/i%3E%3C/span%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Ctable%20bgcolor=`
2. `http://www.example.com/examindex/?p=2343543`

How can I redirect these links using 301 redirects with a *.htaccess* file? I want to redirect 301 link 1 to `http://www.example.com/example.html`  I've tried:

```
redirect 301 /example.html%20text-decoration:%20none%E2%80%9D%3Eexample.com%3C%20%3C/i%3E%3C/span%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Ctable%20bgcolor= http://www.example.com/example.html
```

I want to redirect link 2 to `http://www.example.com/examindex/`.   I've tried:

```
redirect 301 /examindex/?p=2343543 http://www.example.com/examindex/
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Redirect` (mod_alias) matches against the %-decoded path. Also, you can't match the query string with this directive, so it's best to use mod_rewrite for both these redirects (which also matches against the %-decoded path). It's never a good idea to mix both mod_alias and mod_rewrite directives.

At the top of .htaccess, enable the rewrite engine...

```
RewriteEngine On
```

For "link 1" I assume we don't need to match the entire *mashed up* link, just matching the first bit eg. `<space>text-decoration` should be sufficient I would have thought? Note that since we are matching against the %-decoded path, a space is literally a space (), not `%20` - but a space needs to be backslash escaped in the regex (`\`).

```
RewriteRule ^example\.html\ text-decoration /examindex/ [R=301,L]
```

For "link 2" we need to use the `RewriteCond` directive in order to match the query string. The query string is removed from the URL-path before pattern matching (which also applies to a mod_alias `Redirect`).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =p=2343543
RewriteRule ^examindex/$ /examindex/? [R=301,L]
```

The trailing `?` on the substitution is required to remove the query string. (Or you could use the `QSD` flag instead on Apache 2.4+)